# RESTful alternative to 3xx responses for JavaScript based clients

Tags: javascript, rest, http

Several our REST service needs to indicate that further action needs to be taken by the client to fulfill the request (very often that the response to the request can be found under another URI).

In general this is achieved by means of HTTP 3xx responses. However, in case of JavaScript based client the redirection is performed by the browser itself before the response can reach JavaScript code.

Basically what I need is a RESTful way to inform the client (JavaScript code) that the response can be found under another URI and let the client process such a response on its own.

I am thinking about two solutions:

1. HTTP 200 OK with the entity containing URI to follow. I do not like creating a whole entity carrying only URI. I would rather to achieve this via HTTP headers
2. HTTP 204 No Content response with the Location header containing the given URI. But here I am not sure if it is "REST compliant". Is it OK to combine HTTP 204 No Content with Location header that is used mainly in redirection (along with HTTP 3xx responses), or when a new resource has been created?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that, perhaps include a simple example. That would be helpful. In general, if you have a "result" why do not include it in the answer to the action, the client has taken? If your process isn't complete, you response should include a `link:` property, where further URLs are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a process, say of 5 steps. After step 5 there is some result prepared, to which you want to *point* your client, not via `HTTP-3xx`, but in a cleaner way.

I would suggest, that you make use of the `link` property in your `JSON`-response:

```
{
  ...
  "links": [
      ...
      "result": { "href": "/calculation/1234" }
      ...
  ]
}
```

Your client could take this answer and transform it to a simple link/button.

This is conforming with `HATEOAS` (Hypermedia As The Engine Of Application State), indicating, that the current state offers the result under a different location which is referenced.

Comment: Basically you are right. The request initiates some kind of processing and as a response I need to inform the client about URI for retrieving the results. So you suggest returning HTTP 200 OK with the links in the response body, right?

Comment: yes. that's my sugestion. This is a transparent way to lead through the process. After each step, you could include _links_ to the previous step as well as to the next step. Each answer provides the _current_ state the application is in.

Comment: It makes sense and I like the links collection. Actually it it close to what we have now, however, we return a bit different entity. The point is that I would like to avoid returning any body and simulate HTTP 3xx response. But maybe this is the only meaningful way.

Comment: The only way to achive this: you could set `location.href` in your client. But that's not very RESTy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a json response format, you could accept a request parameter like `noredirect` that when present sets the http response code to 200 and set the real response code in the returned object.

```
GET /some/resource
200 OK
{
    status: 200,
    …
}

GET /some/unknown/resource
404 Not Found
{
    status: 404,
    …
}

GET /some/unknown/resource?noredirect
200 OK
{
    status: 404,
    …
}
```